# Ошибка добавления в базу данных полей с формы. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Помогите с проблемой - не прилетают данные на бд MySQL. Использую MySQL Connector. В базе поля равны id, brand, imageName, price и Type
Итак, есть форма:

```
@model WebShop.Models.Bicycle
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddBicycle", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Brand, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imageName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imageName)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="AddBicycle" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
}
```

И контроллер к ней:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
private readonly string _connectionString = "connection";
private readonly MySqlDatabase _database;

public AdminController(MySqlDatabase database)
{
    _database = new MySqlDatabase(_connectionString);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult AddBicycle()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddBicycle(Bicycle bicycle)
{
    var getIdQuery = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id";
    var result = _database.ExecuteQuery(getIdQuery);
    var generatedId = Convert.ToInt32(result[0]["id"]);

    bicycle.Id = generatedId;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var query = "INSERT INTO bicycles (id, brand, price, imageName, Type) " +
                    "VALUES (@Id, @Brand, @Price, @imageName, @Type)";
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"@Id", (int)generatedId},
            { "@Brand", bicycle.Brand },
            { "@Price", Convert.ToDecimal(bicycle.Price) },
            { "@imageName", bicycle.imageName },
            { "@Type", bicycle.Type }
        };

        try
        {
            _database.ExecuteNonQuery(query, parameters);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error occurred while saving data: " + ex.Message);
            return View(bicycle);
        }

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

}
```

Модель Bicycle имеет следующий вид:

```
[Table("bicycles")]
public class Bicycle 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string imageName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

А также сам метод для общения с БД:

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Это что за язык? C#? Где соответствующий тег? В ваших интересах привлечь к вопросу как можно больше людей. 2. Почему вы в ASP.NET так криво используете базу? В ASP.NET все строится на IoC и прочих приблудах, а работа с базой при помощи EF, там не пишут запросы вручную, там делают `db.Table.Add(new("Вася", 13)); db.SaveChanges();`, все, остальное (включая кстати ID) за нас продумает сама база и EF. Ваш метод весьма не оптимальный. 3. Вы отладкой занимались? Что приходит в контроллер? Что отправляется в базу? Может ошибка где? Поставьте точку остановки и смотрите это все.

Comment: Я залез в C# на один проект, использовал то что посоветовали) Если можете, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в ВС запустить отладку с точками останова?

Comment: Точка остановки ставится слева от строки, на которой надо остановиться, там полоса такая, на которую кликаете мышью, появится красный кружок. Либо `Debugger.Break();` в коде. Запуск отладки - сверху кнопка "Плей", либо F5.